# add checkboxes to customize installation with wixtoolset

Tags: c#, checkbox, wix

I have already created MSI package with WIX tool set in C# but I do not know how to add check-boxes for file selection to install.

Do I need to create new installer file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the guide from [Here.](http://www.dizzymonkeydesign.com/blog/misc/adding-and-customizing-dlgs-in-wix-3/)

Also you can check https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/well-done/

Comment: thank you but what I need is that I want to create checkboxes for the user to select which installation that they want to install. for example: if there is 3 installations provided, the user can select all of them or any of those 3 to install.